# NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for 8:Fixnum):

Tags: ruby

I have this error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'each' for 8:Fixnum)`: referring to this line of code:

```
my_hash.key("free").each{|key| my_array.push(key)}
```

What I'm trying to do is "for every entry in my_hash that has the value "free", add it to my_array". 
Is this happening because my_hash.key("free") only returns a single value? If so, how can I change this to do what I wish it?

here is more of the surrounding code for reference:

```
    my_hash = Hash.new
    (8..18).each {|i| my_hash[i] = "free"}
    my_array = Array.new

    ...

    hour_array.each{|hour| my_hash[hour] = "busy"} #this is to show that not every key will have value "free"
    ...
    my_hash.key("free").each{|key| my_array.push(key)}
```

Any explanations would be very appreciated as I am new to Ruby, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?:

```
my_array = []
my_hash = {key1: "not free", key2: "free", key3: "free", key4: "not free", key5: "free"}

my_hash.select{|k,v| my_hash[k] == "free" ? my_array << k : false }

p my_hash
p my_array
```

returns:

```
{:key1=>"not free", :key2=>"free", :key3=>"free", :key4=>"not free", :key5=>"free"}
[:key2, :key3, :key5]
```

Comment: I would like to store the keys, not the values, in my_array

Comment: @SCraig ok I've changed my code (all i did was change the `v` to a `k` in the `select` code block. Have a look.

Comment: @SCraig just updated the return values too, which shouldn't affect the previous code edit anyway.

Comment: Use `inject` instead of php-ish `declare-and-each`. Or, in this example, `select` is good enough: `my_array = my_hash.select{ |k,_| my_hash[k] == "free" }`.

Answer (score 0):

`my_hash.key("free")` returns a single key, not an array as you probably were expecting.

One might select all keys, having the desired value, by:

```
# fails⇒ my_hash.key("free")
my_hash.group_by(&:last)["free"].map(&:first)
```

Here we group hash items by the value, then select the group having `"free"` value and, after all, map it back to keys.

Comment: ok, does group_by permanently change the order of the hash entries?

Comment: What is the problem with reading a documentation on [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) or trying it yourself? No, it won’t, as all unbanged methods on enumerables in ruby it will mutate the newly created object.